# jQuery place div in between two different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get for example all div's `data-id`'s and place a new div with `data-id="6"` in between `data-id="3"` and `data-id="9"`.

The new data-id can be with an id of 1 too, so there's no div before it, but it needs to be before `data-id 2` (if it exists, if not then before the next highest number)

### Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div data-id="1"></div>
    <div data-id="2"></div>
    <div data-id="5"></div>
    <div data-id="7"></div>
    <div data-id="11"></div>
</div>
```

And I need to add a div with `data-id="9"` in between 7 and 11.

I'm still learning jQuery so I don't really have any clue how to achieve this. I tried with `insertBefore()` but it doesn't work like I want it to. It only works when the new div is `data-id="10"` and `data-id="11"` exists in the container.

### Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u3TH4/

Comment: This should give you an idea on how to proceed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495400/jquery-insert-div-at-right-place-in-list-of-divs

Comment: What is the criteria/pattern? You just want to do a random insertion?

Comment: @PSL Actually I have a drag and drop, and if I drag a box into the container, it needs to be in the right place.

Comment: @KristjanKirpu So you know after which div you need to insert to? If you know that insert this div using `sourceElem.after(elementToBeInserted)`

Comment: Could you set up a minimal/[sscce](http://sscce.org/) [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, showing what you're working with?

Comment: @DavidThomas http://jsfiddle.net/u3TH4/ This is the simplest version of my drag and drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $container = $('.container'),
            $d = $container.find('div'),
            $n = $('<div>', { data: { id: 9 }, text: 9 });

// filter the element with smaller data-id
var $a = $d.filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('id') < 9;
}).last();

// If an element with smaller data-id exists
// insert the element after it
if ($a.length) $a.after($n);
// Otherwise prepend it to the container
else $container.prepend($n);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mV9sW/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first way that came to mind:

```
function addDiv(id, content) {
    var $newDiv = $("<div></div>").attr("data-id",id).html(content),
        $container = $("div.container"),
        $divs = $container.find("div[data-id]"),
        inserted = false;
    $divs.each(function(i) {
        if (id < +$(this).attr("data-id")){
            $newDiv.insertBefore(this);
            inserted = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!inserted)
        $newDiv.appendTo($container);
}

addDiv(9,"whatever");
```